# Handling errors with Flask in Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to handle errors in Flask:

```
def handle_error(error):
    if error.status_code == 404:
        return make_response(jsonify({ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Not found" } }), 404)
    else:
        return make_response(jsonify({ "error": { "code": 500, "message": "Internal server error" } }), 500)
```

If the endpoint is not found, it should return a JSON with 404 code. In any other case, it is to return JSON with code 500. I open an endpoint that doesn't exist and get error 500 from Flask:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation for error handling:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def errorhandler(e)
    return xyz
```

You can find documentation here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/

also https://www.codementor.io/@lakshyasri/custom-error-pages-in-flask-xrgye5l5e